# RxSwift: How can I change Bool to ObservableType?

Tags: rx-swift

I am new to RxSwift and I want to achieve this:

A titleTextField,a descTextField,a confirmButton and a submitButton.

The submitButton is unEnable until titleTextField and descTextField's text.count >= 5 and confirmButton is selected, so I write these code:

```
let titleValid = titleTextField.rx.text.orEmpty.map { (text) -> Bool in
    return text.count >= 5
}

let descValid = descTextField.rx.text.orEmpty.map { (text) -> Bool in
    return text.count >= 5
}

let isConfirm = confirmButton.rx.isSelected.asObserver().mapObserver { (selected) -> Bool in
    return selected
}

Observable.combineLatest(titleValid, descValid, isConfirm) { $0 && $1 && $2 }.bind(to: submitButton.rx.isEnabled).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

It's work good with `titleValid` and `descValid`,however,there is an error with `isConfirm`:

```
Argument type 'AnyObserver<Bool>' does not conform to expected type 'ObservableType'
```

How can I change `isConfirm` to `ObservableType`? How to Correct it?

Note the RxSwift's version is 5.0.0

Comment: The `isSelected` state of a button is input only. You need to observe whatever is causing it to be set to true/false instead of observing it directly. Don't store model state in your view. What causes isSelected to change value?

Comment: @DanielT. User taps button cause isSelected changed

Comment: What happens if they tap it a second time, does `isSelected` change back to false or does it stay true?

Comment: @DanielT. Value changed once tap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments contains your answer. It's the tapping of the `confirmButton` that's important.

```
let titleValid = titleTextField.rx.text.orEmpty.map { (text) -> Bool in
    return text.count >= 5
}

let descValid = descTextField.rx.text.orEmpty.map { (text) -> Bool in
    return text.count >= 5
}

let isConfirm = confirmButton.rx.tap
    .scan(false) { current, _ in !current }
    .startWith(false)

isConfirm
    .bind(to: confirmButton.rx.isSelected)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

Observable.combineLatest(titleValid, descValid, isConfirm) { $0 && $1 && $2 }
    .bind(to: submitButton.rx.isEnabled)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help,but with your code the confirm button become selected forever when it’s taped.The confirm button clicked func is : confirmButton.isSelected = !confirmButton.isSelected

Comment: Do not use your view as if it was a model. Keep them separate. I have updated my code to toggle the confirm button.